# Python: CSV file reading and comparison of cell value Vs input value

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file named 'file_name.csv' containing data:

```
account_holder_name,    account_number, account_balance
Ganesh, 12345,  100
Parvati,    23456,  10000
Waheguru,   98765,  12098
```

Input: Above data I have entered using `DictWriter` function.

Expected Output: If I manually enter 98765 it can read name and balance for particular row.

Actual Output:

```
Press 1: To Open New Bank Account or Press 2: To Use Existing Account : 2
Enter account holder number: 12345
Enter correct a/c number
Enter correct a/c number
Enter correct a/c number
```

I used below code:

```
class Account():
    def __init__(self,choice):
        self.choice = choice
        self.file_name = 'file_name.csv'
        self.header = ('account_holder_name', 'account_number', 'account_balance')

        def existing_holder(self):
        self.account_number = int(input("Enter account holder number: "))
        with open(self.file_name, 'r') as csvfile:
            csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=self.header)
            self.header = next(csv_reader)
            if self.header != None:
                for row in csv_reader:
                    if row['account_number'] == self.account_number:
                        print(f"Welcome Mr.{row['account_holder_name']}. Following are the choices. Please select : \nPress 1 deposit money \nPress 2 for withdraw money")
                    else:
                        print("Enter correct a/c number")

customer_visit = int(input("Press 1: To Open New Bank Account or Press 2: To Use Existing Account : "))
acct1 = Account(customer_visit)
if customer_visit ==2:
    acct1.existing_holder()
```

Comment: You need to convert `row['account_number']` to int before checking against `self.account_number`, i.e. `if int(row['account_number']) == self.account_number`

Comment: Do not skip the header line with a `DictReader`: it does it automatically.